# Shell script echo new line to file

Tags: shell, shell-script, echo

I want to echo a new line to a file in between variables in a shell script. Here's my code:

```
var1="Hello"
var2="World!"
logwrite="$var1 [Here's where I want to insert a new line] $var2
echo "$logwrite"  >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

Right now, when I run my script, the file user.txt shows this:

```
Hello World!
```

I want it to show:

```
Hello
World!
```

How do I do this??

EDIT: Here's my shell script:

```
echo -n "What is your first name? "
read first
echo -n "What is your last name? "
read last
echo -n "What is your middle name? "
read middle
echo -n "What is your birthday? "
read birthday
echo -e "First Name: $first /nLast Name: $last /nMiddle Name: $middle /nBirthday: $birthday" >> /Users/matthewdavies/Desktop/user.txt
qlmanage -p "~/Desktop/user.txt"
```

Comment: Do you NEED to create this "logwrite" variable? Can you write `printf "%s\n" $var1 $var2 >> file`?

Comment: No, I don't need to and in my revised script that I've been working on, I don't use the $logwrite variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
var1="Hello"
var2="World!"
logwrite="$var1\n$var2"
echo -e "$logwrite"  >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The `\n` escape sequence indicates a line feed. Passing the `-e` argument to echo enables interpretation of escape sequences.

It may even be simplified further:

```
var1="Hello"
var2="World!"
echo -e "$var1\n$var2"  >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

or even:

```
echo -e "Hello\nWorld! "  >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

Comment: Your example works, but when I incorporate it in my code, it doesn't work. I'll edit my post and add my script in it.

Comment: @dave it appears you are using the wrong slash with the escape sequence. `\n` instead of `/n` should do the trick :)

Comment: That fixes it (using \n instead of /n. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @dave you're more than welcome :)

Comment: on AIX in KSH script I did not require the `-e` flag.

Answer (score 5):

```
var1='Hello'
var2='World!'
echo "$var1" >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
echo "$var2" >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

or actually you don't need vars:

```
echo 'Hello' >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
echo 'World!' >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt
```

there is a problem with john t answer: if any of the vars had the \n string (or some other sequence like \t) they will get translated. one can get something similar to his answer with printf:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'Hello' 'World!'
```

also hmm. i see you are composing the answer into a variable $logwrite. if this is the sole use of this variable, it seems pointless.

I think a here-doc could be more readable, specially if you have lots of line to append to the log:

```
cat >> /Users/username/Desktop/user.txt <<EOF
Hello
World
EOF
```

(this word, EOF, is a delimiter you can choose. it can be any word).

beware that the heredoc will expand $variables, like double quotes. if you don't want this, you quote the heredoc, like <<"EOF"

Comment: the thing is none of the vars have `\n`, hence why I supplied the answer. The "what if" methodology would carry every question on this site into an endless discussion. When he comes to that road he can ask another question :)

Comment: @elias the $logwrite variable was leftover from my edits on the script as I was making changes. I took the $logwrite var out of my code. John T.'s answer did actually work. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, use `printf`. It's POSIX: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34947759/895245